# Angular $http.post 404 and 400 but why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, stripe-payments, http-status-code-400

I keep getting response 400 bad JSON when I send in $scope.result when $scope.result = result.id. I get 404, not found when I pass result.id or $scope.result when $scope.result = result. I'm trying to post from Angular to my Express server with the following code:

```
angular.module('startupApp')
    .controller('stripeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.stripeCallback = function (code, result) {
            if (result.error) {
                window.alert('it failed! error: ' + result.error.message);
            } else {
                window.alert('success! token: ' + result.id);
                $scope.result = result.id;
                $http.post('api/stripe', $scope.result)
                    .success(function (response) {
                    // not sure if anything goes here; not looking for a response.
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

The object I want to pass in looks like this in the JS console:

```
Object {id: "tok_15cAbpL4TQAw2alUSkdXzIN5", livemode: false, created: 1425368309, used: false, object: "token"…}
```

card: Object
client_ip: "76.126.66.106"
created: 1425368309
id: "tok_15cAbpL4TQAw2alUSkdXzIN5"
livemode: false
object: "token"
type: "card"
used: false
**proto**: Object

I'm using Angular Payments with Stripe.

???????????????????????????????????????????
UPDATE:
This is what I'm getting in the JS console in entirety for the previous code.

```
 GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js 404 (Not Found)
stripe.controller.js:15 Object {id: "tok_15cBUlL4TQAw2alUb8yGnalO"}
stripe.controller.js:16 Object {id: "tok_15cBUlL4TQAw2alUb8yGnalO"}
angular.js:9814 POST http://localhost:9000/api/stripe 404 (Not Found)
```

and the headers:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/stripe
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:37
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/stripe
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
{id: "tok_15cBUlL4TQAw2alUb8yGnalO"}
id: "tok_15cBUlL4TQAw2alUb8yGnalO"
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 03 Mar 2015 08:35:16 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Here is the update with the response header explicitly declared:

```
angular.module('startupApp')
    .controller('stripeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.stripeCallback = function (code, result) {
            if (result.error) {
                window.alert('it failed! error: ' + result.error.message);
            } else {
                window.alert('success! token: ' + result.id);
                $scope.result = result.id;
                console.log({id: result.id});
                console.log({id: $scope.result});
                //$http.post('api/card', $scope.card)
                var req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/stripe',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': application/json
                    },
                    data: {id: $scope.result}
                }
                $http.post(req)
                    .success(function (response) {
                    // not sure if anything goes here; not looking for a response.
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

This is the JS Console response:

```
ReferenceError: application is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.stripeCallback (stripe.controller.js:22)
    at angular-payments.js:793
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14384)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14483)
    at angular-payments.js:792
    at Object.Stripe.token.a.create.Stripe.request.success ((index):2)
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):3)
    at Object.Stripe.a._receiveChannelRelay [as onMessage] ((index):2)
    at Object.Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.H.Socket.t.concat.incoming ((index):2)
    at f ((index):2)angular.js:11594 (anonymous function)angular.js:8544 $getangular.js:14485 $get.Scope.$applyangular-payments.js:792 (anonymous function)(index):2 Stripe.token.a.create.Stripe.request.success(index):3 (anonymous function)(index):2 Stripe.a._receiveChannelRelay(index):2 Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.H.Socket.t.concat.incoming(index):2 f
```

Comment: Take a look at `Content-Type` header which is being sent by Angular. Sometimes when it's set incorrectly (i.e. it's "text/plain" and serwer expects JSON) server will respond with `404`.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, what is the content-type header?

Comment: Possible, since in this case you are simply sending a string (the result's id). You could then also try to simply change it to `$http.post('api/stripe', {id: $scope.result}`

Comment: I tried it but I still get 404. I tried a few iterations of it. It's a good idea and makes sense so I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: I'm sure maybe the question is beneath you but I'm seriously struggling with a few things doing my best to learn on my lonesome. please help if you can.

Comment: @rashadb Have a look [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#http-headers) on how to inspect headers. `Content-Type` header describes what kind of data are you sending to the server. If server is expecting JSON (in which case header should be `application/json`) and you're sending something different (for instance, `text/plain`), server could respond with `404`. If that's the case, force Angular to send a correct header (see [this doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for example).

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it is an issue with the headers though.  My request header is Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8/My response header is Content-Type:text/html

The request payload is a key value pair

Comment: @rashadb Can you post contents of the request and the response from the Developer Tools? Something else might be broken, i.e. URL, other headers etc. Maybe we can spot something.

Comment: Ya, I just tried explicitly renaming the header and received "application is not defined" as a JS Console response

Comment: Header is a string, so it should be `"application/json"` not `application/json`.

Comment: Other than that, headers look fine I think. Are you 100% sure that "http://localhost:9000/api/stripe" is a valid endpoint?

Comment: I had another endpoint, api/card and I pretty much copied and pasted one to the other, so it should be. I changed the names accordingly that's about all. I did notice that the api/card runs though not correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72124/discussion-between-rashadb-and-kamituel).